# React Native NavigatorIOS Child Component Doesn't Update When Parent State Changes

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to get a side menu to open up when I press on a notifications button on the NavigatorIOS React Native component, but the child component doesn't seem to update when the parent's state changes. Thus, pressing on the notifications button is not doing what I want it to do. The parent and child component are as follows. How can I get the child component to update when the parent state changes using NavigatorIOS?

```
export default class App extends React.Component {



    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            rightMenuOpen: false
        }

        this.rightButtonPress = this.rightButtonPress.bind(this);
      }

    rightButtonPress() {
        this.setState({rightMenuOpen: true});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <NavigatorIOS
                initialRoute={{
                component: Home,
                rightButtonIcon: source=require('./img/notifications.png'),
                onRightButtonPress: this.rightButtonPress,
                passProps: {index: 1, rightMenuOpen: this.state.rightMenuOpen},
                }}
                style={{flex: 1}}
            />
        )
    }
}

class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    render() {
        const menu = <Switch/>
        return (

            <View style={styles.body}>
                <SideMenu
                    menu={infoText}
                    menuPosition="right"
                    disableGestures={true}
                    isOpen={this.props.rightMenuOpen}
                >
                    <WebView
                        source={{uri: 'https://www.michigandaily.com/'}}
                        bounces={false}
                    />
                </SideMenu>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're trying this won't work because changes to the value of passProps won't cause a re-render. What you need is a way to pass a signal to the child from the parent using the Event Emitter or a State Management framework.

**Example of how to use the event emitter:**
https://colinramsay.co.uk/2015/07/04/react-native-eventemitters.html

I also would recommend using a **state management** framework like Redux or Mobx (I prefer Mobx for its simplicity).

You can learn more about Mobx here: http://mobx.js.org